# Ubuntu 18.04 Git starts its own ssh-agent instead of using the existing agent

Tags: git, ssh, gnome, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring-daemon

I'm having an issue I don't fully understand with my new machine where the first time I run a `git` command after a restart, it starts its own ssh-agent instead of using the existing one that already has my key added. Symptoms are as follows:

When I first restart my machine and open a new terminal, I run `ps aux | grep [s]sh-agent` and get

`me+  3924  0.0  0.0  11308   320 ?        Ss   20:19   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu`

Running `env|grep SSH` gives me

`SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
SSH_AGENT_PID=3924`

And `ssh-add -l` returns the right fingerprint

BUT as soon as I run any `git` command, I get prompted for my ssh password and I end up with two ssh-agents

`me+  3748  0.0  0.0  11308   328 ?        Ss   20:37   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
me+ 13364  0.0  0.0  11304  1524 ?        S    20:40   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh`

This is only mildly annoying, once per restart which hopefully will be less often as I get this machine more situated, but annoying enough that I want to get to the bottom of it and I have no idea where to start; I haven't seen this issues with previous machines. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: [disable gnome-keyring ssh integration](https://askubuntu.com/q/545172)?

Comment: @phd that just causes it to not store my ssh identity and prompt in terminal instead of a graphic prompt :/ is there some fundamental difference between keyring in gnome/18.04 and whatever the default is on 16.04?

Comment: I think you are experiencing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1586835  (notice how one path has `.ssh` and the other has just `ssh`)